# Is it possible for TS to now the type of the second param of a function based on the type of the first one

Tags: typescript

Im working on a way to simplify our redux setup and am wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
type Action = {type: "foo", payload: string} | {type: "bar", payload: number} | {type: "baz"}

function Test<T extends Action>(action: T['type'], payload?: T['payload']) {
    return
}

Test("foo", "string")
Test("bar", 1337)
Test("baz")
```

The idea is that if you type "foo" as the first param only string should be allowed as second param, "bar" only numbers and "baz" as first param  should be able to leave the second param empty.

Comment: Missing the "real topic" of this question a bit, but I can really recommend you look into the official Redux Toolkit, as that is really geared towards TypeScript and you will not write stuff like action types (neither the strings nor the typescript types) or action creators by hand any more.

Comment: Also missing the 'real topic', but there's also [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions), which does a lot of this work for you

Comment: It's really not connected to redux. Based on the first param of a function I want TS to know the type of the second param.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a convoluted solution, but it works

```
interface ActionWithPayloadDefinition {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
    complex: {
        name: string
        age: number
    }
}
type ActionWithPayloadName = keyof ActionWithPayloadDefinition
type ActionWithoutPayloadName = 'baz'

// Use function overload: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads
function Test<T extends ActionWithoutPayloadName>(type: T): void
function Test<T extends ActionWithPayloadName>(type: T, payload: ActionWithPayloadDefinition[T]): void
function Test(type: string, payload?: any){
    // Do something
}

Test("foo", "string")
Test("bar", 1337)
Test("baz")
Test("complex", { name: 'testing', age: 999 })
```

I introduce a `ActionWithPayloadDefinition` interface, which we use to map the name of the action to the type of payload. I've add a `complex` type here to demonstrate that we can have more complex payloads.

In the `Test` function, rather than using a full `Action` as the generic parameter, we only use the action name as the generic parameter. This allow us to use that parameter to map it back to the expected payload type.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iA6sMACwAU4BPAGyzgBMARCGUA7EZAbwChkfkYssALmQBnMFFABzADTdeAIzhRhIAK4BbedDk8EWdQAcKEAB7CuvS8hBx1EYWIkhJOq3En3rGrVFcBfTgCwMgMUdEwcfCJSSmoaADlbFABeZABrCDIsGDQMViiScipaBiYQFhxOYNDciLwCQixVMBjihKTkVIByRQAvLs5OAHoh5ABVERQYVRA8nGQsADdoNuFCMDADEUERgHd9gDpqiBEECQMwCjhnA6woSSGaLAQRIcJrmnkBNKGAJiHprM6iIDut1BQAMSAuYgAC0SxWcREnGhdWQABUTmAADzo5CmSAgGgiWr5BpNFpFOKJOwAPgAFMdhOiAJTCRZYYA0FEzGEYrG4-EmQnE0mRBqtalJBlMjHSZAGKm0YThMnRJX0RjMOoAbXRAF02cgOVyeUDWPyxIyQp5HFJ5YrYrQAPzCa5kFkWXgjZB0LCifQQIhSQKDTFWgBE-CwEflEbtzgjLM44bA9IjiigseQAEYAMx5gDsydT6b6SZTWPTekMxhM2fY1iSwi6kDEUi68vcngAnH3kH4WUA)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank!